# Observer is triggered multiple times when calling postValue only once from LiveData

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-lifecycle

I'm using an AndroidViewModel with a LiveData that is observed in a Fragment.

However, even though I'm using postValue from the LiveData, the observer registered in an activity triggers more than once. I know it's a common problem on LiveData but I haven't found yet a concrete solution.

Does somebody know why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Note: u need to provide the code.

Answer

multiple triggers Causes:

1. [Default] onChange() method in the observer will be called when the fragment is created (u will receive the last value emitted before the fragment get destroyed)
2. Or, you are using livedata.observe(this,...), (if it's true you need to use livedata.observe(viewlifecycleowner,...)

Resource:
https://proandroiddev.com/5-common-mistakes-when-using-architecture-components-403e9899f4cb

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodels-and-livedata-patterns-antipatterns-21efaef74a54